# Hardcoded JsonpResult values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonpResult  getTestValues(int? entityId, int? id)
        {
            return JsonpResult(WebResult.Success());
        }
```

I have a AJAX call that invokes this controller and has to parse the data object returned. How can I modify the above to return the following?

```
{"data":[{"T1":"t1@test.com","T11":"1234-1234-1234-1234"},
{"T2":"t2@test.com","T22":"1234-1234-1234-1234"}]}
```

I need this for testing the UI framework that I am working on. Any suggestions on how to return the above hardcoded data?

Comment: What is a `JsonpResult`? I've only ever seen `JsonResult`.

Comment: @vcsjones a jsonpresult allows you to deliver json via a cross domain ajax request. Decent article: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx

Comment: @Jesse I know what JSONP is, I've just never seen the `JsonpResult` class. Seems 3rd party.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using an anonymous type:

```
return JsonpResult {
    Data = new {
        data = new List<object> {
           new { T1 = "t1@test.com", T11 = "1234-1234-1234-1234" },
           new { T2 = "t2@test.com", T22 = "1234-1234-1234-1234" },
        }
    }
};
```